# Is this the best way to get the size of a Paper via CUPS?

Tags: macos, cups, ppd

I've got a CUPS job control file (these can be found at /var/spool/cups/cnnnnn). I need to get the actual dimensions of the print that was made.

This is the way I've figured out to do it:

1. Get the paper name using the `media` attribute. (e.g. `Letter`)
2. Get the printer uri from the `printer-uri` attribute. (e.g. `ipp://localhost/printers/MyPrinter`)
3. Get the printer name by passing the printer uri to the `IPP_GET_PRINTER_ATTRIBUTES` operation and getting the `printer-name` attribute. (e.g. `MyPrinter`)
4. Get the path to the PPD passing the printer name to the the `cupsGetPPD` method.
5. Open the PPD passing the path to the PPD to the `ppdOpenFile` method.
6. Get the paper size by passing the PPD and paper name to the `ppdPageSize` method.

This will work, but it seems a bit roundabout. Is there a more efficient way of getting what I need?

Answer (score 1):

The job control file will contain all the job options of the file used for printing. There are 3 types of job options:

1. ones which were specifically and explicitely selected by the user on the commandline or by clicking some GUI elements (these ones will appear in the control files);
2. ones which were implicitely set because they are contained in and read from a user-specific `~/.lpoptions` or a system-wide `/etc/cups/lpoptions` file (the user specific file has been migrated to `~/.cups/lpoptions` in more recent versions of CUPS (these ones will also appear in the control files);
3. ones which were added by CUPS by parsing the PPD and looking for default settings contained there (these ones will ***not*** appear in the control files, since CUPS only evaluates them in the moment the job is processed -- which may be 2 days in the future if you used `-o job-hold-until=indefinite`.

If you know the printqueuename and the cupsserver used, you can query the default queue settings for that combo with these two commands:

```
lpoptions -h cupsserver \
          -U username \
          -d printqueuename
```

This will return all current settings as noted in the `(.)loptions` file(s).

```
lpoptions -h cupsserver \
          -U username \
          -d printqueuename \
          -l
```

This will return all user-selectable settings contained in the PPD. Note how the asterisks `*` marks the default setting for each option. Also note that `-U username` is significant here -- different users may use different default settings...

Now watch out for the results of these commands noting the `PageSize` used...

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the CUPS_GET_PPD request to get the ppd directly instead of steps 3 and 4. This seems more efficient.